# How to superscript a label in Vuetify textfield

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I use Vuetify. I like to have in the label the text "Target m²"

I tried with `<sup>2</sub>` but it doesn't work

```
<v-text-field 
  label="Target (in m<sup>2</sup>)"
   v-model="form.target" :error-messages="errors.target" > 
</v-text-field>
```

How can I i superscript in the label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use named slot [`label`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#slots) :

```
<v-text-field  v-model="form.target" :error-messages="errors.target" >
   <template #label>
      <label>Target (in m<sup>2</sup>)</label>
   </template>
 </v-text-field>
```

please check this  [example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#label)

PS :  `#label` is a shorthand of `v-slot:label`

Answer (score 0):

**@Boussadjra Brahim**'s answer is correct but we need to define `label` prop as well in the `v-text-field` otherwise the label that is defined in the slot get disappeared.

so the correct way is as following

```
<v-text-field 
  label="Target"
  v-model="form.target"
  :error-messages="errors.target"
>
  <template v-slot:label>
    Target (in m<sup>2</sup>)
  </template>
</v-text-field>
```

I hope the answer is helpful and the credit goes to [jacekkarczmarczyk](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/11533)